# Python adds only first entry to excel file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a list of urls which im parsing for a contact section on that side. So far so good.
After i found the contact path i wanna write the url + the parsed path to my excel file.
The problem is: it only writes the last value. Im sure im failing the loop but i cant find the mistake.

I am new at coding please don't be mad :D

Using Python 3.7.3

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import xlrd

Workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("AlleDSKosmetik.xlsx")

Worksheet = Workbook.sheet_by_name("Tabelle1")


def FindFormular(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
    except:
        print(url + ' nicht erreichbar oder Fehlerhaft')
        return
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        Formular = link['href']
        parsed_url = urlparse(Formular).path
        parsed_url = str(parsed_url)
        if parsed_url.find('kontakt') > -1:
            finalFormular = (url + parsed_url)
            print(finalFormular)
            data = pd.DataFrame({'Formulare': [finalFormular]})
            datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter('Formulare.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
            data.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Tabelle1')
            datatoexcel.save()
i = 0
for row_curser in range(1, 10):
    excel = Worksheet.cell(row_curser, 8).value
    url = 'http://' + excel
    FindFormular(url)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Add print statement in ur for loop to debug the issue and find out what exactly is happening, debugging is the best way to find out the issue and also saves ur time .

Comment: Please add a clear headline to your questions!

Comment: Sorry, hope its fine like this

Comment: it's not clear from your question what is the last value you are referring to ? can you share the expected vs actual output

Comment: im copying ulrs out of a excel file and parse them in my function to find the path where the contact section on the website is. After i found that i want to write it in another excel file just like that:  pulling stackoverflow.com -> parsing it for stackoverflow.com/contact -> writing stackoverflow.com/contact in the excel file. At the monent i have for example 10 of these urls but it only writes the last url of the list in the excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the value of excel and url every time, but not saving the in between values. Small example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = []
c = 0

for i in range(len(x)):
    b = c
    c+= 2
```

will return `b = 8`, while

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    b.append(c)
    c+= 2
```

will return `b = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

Hope this makes it clear for you. (note the difference between `b = c` and `b.append(c)`)

In your case use:

```
url = []

for row_curser in range(0, 9):
    excel = Worksheet.cell(row_curser, 8).value
    url.append('http://' + excel)
    FindFormular(url[row_curser])
    i += 1
```

best way to write it to an excel:

```
for row_curser in range(0, 9):
    excel = Worksheet.cell(row_curser, 8).value
    url.append('http://' + excel)
    i += 1

url = pd.DataFrame(url)
url.to_excel('excel_name.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes i understand whats wrong and you also understand your example but to be honest i cant find the way to fix it. What you say makes totally sence to me

Comment: What do you want to save in the end? the url's? @user123456789

Comment: Yes, i wanna safe the parsed url`s of the other excel file. Its all working besides the writing part. How can i fix the overwriting so it writes all values and not just the last?

Comment: http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/anfahrt/
http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/anfahrt/
http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/impressum/
http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/
http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/impressum/
http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/datenschutzerklaerung/     thats the output of the console. And thats what i wanna write inside my excel file but atm i only get this one "http://1-2haarfrei.de/de/kontakt95/datenschutzerklaerung/" inside my file

Comment: @user123456789 See my answer, I added a suggested solution for you

Comment: Thank you. But sadly i got many errors after i tried it :( Guess i just dont get the hang...

Comment: @user123456789 I forgot to update this line: FindFormular(url[row_curser]). Hope it works now

Comment: @user123456789 I also changed the for loop from range(1, 10) to range(0, 9), since indexes start at 0 in Python

Comment: Yes way better now :) There is one error left : IndexError: list index out of range is this because it wants to get the urls out of the above created url array? because i refer to the place of the urls with my excel variable

Comment: @user123456789 Did you see my previous comment about the range?

Comment: Sorry i guess i just overlooked it. There are no errors left now but still it only wrote the last one in the excel file and i have no clue why

Comment: There probably the same fault occurs. You save the url every time to the excel, but you are overwriting the excel file

Comment: http://1147.jimdo.com/kontakt/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/erice/Desktop/Arbeit/Ei/K-Formulare/sort.py", line 34, in <module>
    FindFormular(url[row_curser]) Sorry for beeing dumb as hell
  File "c:/Users/erice/Desktop/Arbeit/Ei/K-Formulare/sort.py", line 26, in FindFormular
    url = pd.DataFrame(url)
  File "C:\Users\erice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 485, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: @user123456789 if your goal is to just write the url's to excel you can use url = pd.DataFrame(url)
url.to_excel('excel_name.xlsx', index=False) as mentioned above.
If any of my answers/comments helped you, please consider upvoting them :)

Comment: i tried it as you said but i get the error that the dataframe isnt called properly

Comment: a = 'hello1'
b = 'hello2'
c = 'hello3'
url = []

for i in range (0,3):
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        url.append(a)
    elif i ==1:
        url.append(b)
    elif i == 2:
        url.append(c)

url = pd.DataFrame(url)
print(url)

url.to_excel('test123.xlsx', index=False)

Comment: @user123456789 above in the coment i posted a test script I used. It should work

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting data in loop so last item is saved. You can modify your code according to following sample.

```
finalFormular = []
for link in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    finalFormular.append(link)

if finalFormular:
    data = pd.DataFrame({'Formulare': finalFormular})
    datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Formulare.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
    data.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Tabelle1')
    datatoexcel.save()
```